# Sums of numbers and divisibility

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-factorization

Consider the numbers from 1 to n, and the random permutation $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n$. We sum up the permutations in order to get $s_1, s_2, \cdots s_n$ with $s_1=a_1$. The question is, for which $n$ does there exist a permutation such that $n$ is a factor of $s_k$ for all $k$ from 1 to n?

I have tried to find properties of the numbers at each step but nothing has worked. Can someone give a solution?

Comment: I don't understand what are $s_1, s_2, \cdots s_n.$

Comment: So ... to clarify.  Each $a_i$ is equal to one of the $1,2,3....,n$ but they are all distinct so that for any $k\le n$ we will have *some* $a_i = k$.  Correct.  Now are $s_k = a_1 + a_2 +.... + a_k$?

Comment: yes. That is what i meant

Comment: Can someone please answer this question?

Comment: Are you sure you mean $n$ is a factor and not that $k$ is a factor?

Comment: There still is no clear definition of the $s_k$'s *inside* your post (only at the end of fleablood's comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works for $n =1$.
The reason being that in order for $s_1$ to be divisible by $n$ you need $a_1 = n$.
But then $s_2$ is not divisible by $n$, since $s_2 = a_1 + a_2 = n + a_2$ and $1 \leq a_2 < n$.